# dropzone.js Is it possible to show filename in the preview?

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

By Default, in the preview state, I have to hover on the image preview to see the filename.
but Is it possible to put filename outside the hoverzone? (see the screenshot)
[image]

This is my try but not work

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <div class="dz-filename">
        <span data-dz-name></span>
    </div>
  <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> 


  Manga Title:<input type="text" name="title" />  <br>
  Chapter:<input type="text" name="chapter" /> <br>

  <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the file name in any event in add it to the preview element, here is an example in the `addedfile` event:

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

    init: function() {

        this.on('addedfile', function(file){

            var preview = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-preview');
            preview = preview[preview.length - 1];

            var imageName = document.createElement('span');
            imageName.innerHTML = file.name;

            preview.insertBefore(imageName, preview.firstChild);

        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in your previewTemplate, use like this

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
              <div class="dz-details">
               <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name class="badge badge-success"></span></div>
                <img data-dz-thumbnail style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
                <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name class="badge badge-success"></span></div>
                <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                <div class="dz-details"> 
                 </div>
                <img src="assets/img/fileRemoveIcon.png" style="width: 40px;margin-top: -227px;margin-left: 70px;" alt="remove" data-dz-remove />

                </div>
            </div>`
```